# Check Webserver Connectivity Speed in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, connection

I am using a c# code to call webservice **SOAP**. Actually, I want to write a code to check the connectivity speed between the client and the web server, and based on the result there are 3 results:

1. **Good Connection**: I will send the request to the webserver.
2. **Poor Connection**: I will tell the customer the connection is poor please try later.
3. **Connection Lost**: I will tell the customer there is no connection with the server.

**Edit:** Before sending any request to the webservice, I want to check only the speed of the connectivity only, and to know based on what I will know if the connectivity is poor.

For example:
**URL:** http://abc123/henks/com.oper.gateway.sava.wcp?organization=o=oper,cn=henks,cn=SIT,o=abc.com

Comment: You can find the http client doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0#examples). And you could measure API response time using [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0#examples). I'm not sure if this is what you meant, so please try making clearer what you are asking.